# exec() and phantomjs issue with absolute paths

Tags: php, linux, exec, phantomjs

I'm using [**phantomJS**](http://phantomjs.org/) for the purposes of programmatically taking screenshots of a webpage. My webserver runs on Linux 64 bit.

#### The Scenario

My `test.php` file

```
exec('./phantomjs --version', $o, $e);
print_r($o);
echo $e;
```

I open `test.php` in a browser. The out put I get is:

```
1.9.1 // version number
0 // exit code
```

This proves that I can run commands through `exec()` and `phantomJS` is working perfectly.

#### The Issue

Now when I replace the above code with:

```
exec('./phantomjs http://mywebsite.com/test.js', $o, $e);
print_r($o);
echo $e;
```

The output is:

```
Array ( ) // empty output
139 // exit code which on investigating turned out to be segmentation fault
```

I also tried:

```
exec('./phantomjs ./test.js', $o, $e); // since phantomjs and test.js are in same folder
```

but the result was the same (segfault)

**test.js** code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://www.rediff.com/';
page.open(url, function (status) {
    phantom.exit();
});
```

This makes me believe that using the full path as the second argument of `phantomJS` is causing it to crash. Thus, the things that I'm wondering are:

- Am I right in my assumption?
- Or is it because of some restriction on my webserver which is blocking `exec()` from accessing the `.js` file through absolute URL?

Comment: I'd recommend using the full path both to phantomjs and the script you want to run, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/phantomjs /some/directory/test.js`

Comment: Q1. Are you using SELinux? (e.g. it appears to be used by default with Centos)
Q2. Does it work if you run php-cgi, instead of running it as a PHP module?

Comment: @NiklasLindblad I tried with full paths but same result

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of searching and testing I got it to work with following additions:

```
//throws a lot of errors because searching some libraries
$cmd = 'unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH ;';
$cmd.= ' /abs/path/to/phantomjs';
$cmd.= ' /abs/path/to/script.js';

//set environment variable to node source
putenv('PATH=/abs/path/to/node/bin/');

//now exec the cmd and pipe the errors to stdout
exec($cmd.' 2>&1', $output);

//and output the results
print_r($output);
```

I'm not the best server admin, so I can not explain everything in detail, but the lines above generate an pdf. Yeah.

Comment: unsetting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH worked for me too. If anyone knows WHY, i'm open for some explaining. But thanks for this!

Comment: This was the only way I could get my project to run locally on OSX Mavericks (using MAMP). When running the same project remotely on an Ubuntu server, I didn't need any of this sorcery.

Comment: This was also the solution for me on OSX Mavericks with MAMP. Interestingly it worked on Yosemite without unsetting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH. Interested in the reasoning if anybody knows.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. [PHP + PhantomJS Rasterize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392407/php-phantomjs-rasterize)  I found that phantomjs does not like running from an apache process.  Try running your exec command from the command line:

```
php -r "exec('./phantomjs http://mywebsite.com/test.js', $o, $e); print_r($o); echo $e;"
```

If this works you have a few options:

1.) Some have suggested modifying sudoers to give no password sudo permissions for apache user to phantomjs binary

2.) Do like I did and run your script as a cron.

Answer (score 0):

Try to place `test.js` in folder where `test.php` located (when calling `exec('./phantomjs ./test.js', $o, $e);`) or use full path.

Comment: As I pointed out in my post test.js and test.php are in the same folder already. Also I'm facing issues when I'm using full path.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue to be with selinux (which is now disabled by default on all production server builds as standard).

## in file /etc/selinux/config find line containing:

SELINUX=

## and change it to this:

SELINUX=disabled

## run command (to take immediate effect without reboot)

/usr/sbin/setenforce 0